# Need a counter to update daily

Tags: javascript, counter

I am looking for a quick script that will update a number daily. This is for something like the number of days without an accident in the work place.

I want it to to put an link to the HTML page for it in the startup group in XP (yes XP, company is a little behind) and have it run at bootup. I may add more stuff later but this is the main purpose.

So each day it needs to update the number by 1 based on the previous days number, so it is most likely going to have to be read and written to a file. If the browser is closed or the system rebooted it should not update increment the browser unless it is a different day.

Can someone point me to a good way of doing this. I was thinking javascript, but I am open. I have no access to a database.

Thanks

Comment: This is far too broad a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you need to read and write a file, JavaScript in a browser is probably not a good choice for this.  JavaScript can be used as a client-side browser-based technology to send requests to the server, though.  Then the server-side technology can persist this data.  If many people are going to be executing this at the same time (when they all turn on their computers in the morning) then expect concurrent requests.  Databases are good at handling those, manually writing to a file not so much.

Comment: It will be on a TV with a dedicated computer so it won't do multiple updates an only admins will have access to computer and folder.

Answer (score 3):

This script should do the trick

**HTML**

```
<div id="counter">1</div>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

**JS**

```
setInterval(function(){
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML);
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = (value+1).toString();
},86400000); //86400000 = 1 day in milliseconds

var btn = document.getElementById('reset');
btn.onclick=function(){
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "0";
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/khe67/3/

Comment: Thanks, I will look at this. I also just found that you can have a daily counter in MS Excel. If I can port that number to Powerpoint, that may be easier to do and also for the manager to add slides if need be. Anyone seen this done.

Answer (score 0):

Well than you may wanna use `HTML5` to save variables within the `web browser`, so if you happen to reload or reboot the computer you still have your variables saved. Code may look something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hello HTML5</title>
<script>
window.onload = function (){
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
        var goodDays;
        var oldTime = localStorage.getItem("oldTime"); 
        var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        if(!oldTime || oldTime==""){
            goodDays = 1;
            localStorage.setItem("oldTime", timestamp);
            localStorage.setItem("dayCounter", goodDays);
        }else{
            var timeCheck = oldTime + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            goodDays = localStorage.getItem("dayCounter");
            if(timestamp > timeCheck){
                goodDays++;
                localStorage.setItem("oldTime", timestamp);
                localStorage.setItem("dayCounter", goodDays);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("dCounter").innerHTML=goodDays; 
    }else{
        alert("geat a real browser");
    }
}

function resetDays(){
    localStorage.setItem("oldTime", "");
    localStorage.setItem("dayCounter", "");
    location.reload();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="display:inline">DAYS WITH OUT INCENDENTS </div><div style="display:inline" id="dCounter"></div>
<div style="cursor:pointer" onclick="resetDays()">Reset</div>
</body>
</html>
```